# how to detect input that is not in english?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, vb.net

I'm trying to detect if input is not in English chars, will disallow the input and i'm using code below to validate the input. The code works fine if the input is in Non-English, for example, **'ກັ​ຫ​ກ່​ຫ່'**, **'你好**'. When the input contains English chars and Non-English chars, the code below will allow the input to go through and i don't want this to happen. How can i disallow the input if there is any Non-English chars detected in the input?

```
If Not Regex.IsMatch(Edt.Text, "[A-Za-z0-9]") Then
End If
```

Comment: There's no such thing as "English chars". Those are Latin letters and Arabic numerals.

Comment: By allowing [A-Za-z] you are not only limiting to English but a whole lot of languages that use the latin alphabet. For example, "Hola" is a Spanish word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this regex:

```
^[A-Za-z0-9]*$
```

Comment: Besides, Latin letter and Arabic digit. How can i allow characters like spaces, !, &, ^, (), - and others?

Comment: @Blueguy33, Insert them between `[]`, i.e.: `^[A-Za-z0-9()!^]*$`

Comment: But the -, \ and spaces can't just insert that way. How to allow 3 of these?

Comment: @Blueguy33, `^[A-Za-z0-9()!^\\- ]*$`

Comment: getting error, **parsing "^[A-Za-z0-9()!^\\- ]*$" - [x-y] range in reverse order.**

Comment: @Blueguy33, Strange.. Try this one: `^[A-Za-z0-9()!^\\ \-]*$`

Answer (score 1):

That `Regex.IsMatch` call will succeed if `Edt.Text` contains *any* Latin letter or Arabic digit.

First, you'll need to define the problem more clearly; in particular, you'll need to decide exactly which characters are permitted (think about spaces and punctuation).

Then you'll need to modify the regular expression so it matches the entire string, probably something like:

```
"^[something]*$"
```

where `something` is left as an exercise.